# API Gateway Pattern + OAuth

Tags: authentication, oauth, microservices, api-gateway

Suppose that I have mobile application that needs to authenticate using a OAuth2 flow. 
I have two options:

- The OAuth Service behind an API Gateway.
- The app calls directly the OAuth Service, and then send requests to the API Gateway.

What is the best practice? What are the cons and pros of each option?

Answer (score 0):

The latest BCP (best current practice)says that you should keep tokens out of js entirely.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps

You need some kind of dynamic backend server for doing Oauth. Between your app and this dynamic backend server = Api gateway you use session based authentication.